# Как хранить промежуточные данные в React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest

Ребят, всем привет! Помогите решить проблему. У меня приложение на реакте, которое get запросом получает заявки с API и post запросом туда их отправляет. Проблема вот в чем, когда уходит post запрос заявка не сразу попадает в БД, там по скрипту по-моему через  1 час она только попадает в БД и появляется в API. Мне надо чтобы заявка, которую отправили сразу появлялась на фронте, а потом когда она в API появится тянулась уже оттуда. Я сначала думал просто создать стейт переменную, в которую будет попадать данные из формы и рендериться на фронте, а каждый час стейт очищался бы, но потом эту идею отбросил так как каждая заявка примерно час отправляется а не все разом уходят в API. Надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: json->stringify->localStorage

Comment: Меняй бэкенд - пусть он сообщает, что заявка есть, но ещё не обработана. Мало ли, может я в приватном окне работал или через полчаса зашёл с другого устройства (например, был с компа, а теперь проверяю с телефона)?

Comment: @Qwertiy в приложение можно зайти только с компа по внутренней сетке, и видят эти заявки все пользователи в сети, то есть нет ролирования

Comment: Так тем более - соседний пользователь зайдёт - и как он должен увидеть то, что у меня на компе хранится?